# Isomorphism mapping of a function

Tags: abstract-algebra

The map ϕ: Z->Z defined by ϕ(n)=n+1 for n an element of Z is one to one and onto Z. Give the definition of a binary operation * on Z such that ϕ is an isomorphism mapping.

a)  onto

I am a little confused how to go about this. I know for the homomorphism property I would want to show f(x times y)=f(x)*f(y) but how do I come up with the definition of the binary operation?

Answer (score 1):

A binary operation $*$ is just a mapping, $*:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ that takes ordered pairs of the form $(m,n)$ to some element $a\in \mathbb{Z}$. We usually denote this by $a=m*n$.

Then we define the group as the ordered pair $(\mathbb{Z},*)$.

So if we have a function $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\phi(n)=n+1$, and under the first group we have normal addition $+$, under the second we will define the operation of $*$ so that $\phi$ induces an isomorphism of $(\mathbb{Z},+)\cong (\mathbb{Z},*)$.

If we define for $*(a,b)=a+b-1$ then we have $$\phi(x+y)=x+y+1$$ and $$ \phi(x)*\phi(y)=(x+1)*(y+1)=(x+1+y+1)-1=x+y+1$$

Thus we have shown $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ to $(\mathbb{Z},*)$. I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP: a group is not a set together with *any* old binary operation. You need it to be associative and admit an identity element and inverses. Eoin has left it for you to verify that this operation makes $\mathbb{Z}$ into a group.